# How do single page app router libraries work

Tags: javascript, html

How do single page app router libraries (eg. react-router) load a path without getting document not found? I get that they must intercept `window.location.pathname` which then allows them to display views but how do they prevent getting a document not found error when loading a path initially?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Apart from adding to my overall understanding of how browsers work, I'm trying to implement my own small routing library. I'm writing an app in pure JS, no frameworks (there are reasons for this), but I would like to be able to having routing capability.

Comment: What do you mean by "routing" at a single page application? Why do you not utilize fragment identifiers?

Comment: Yes I could absolutely use fragment identifiers, or query parameters for that matter. I'm interested in how router libraries like react-router or vue-router manage to intercept a deep URL path in single page app.

Comment: Have not tried react-router or vue-router. One approach would be to use `ServiceWorker` to respond to all requests

Comment: Interesting. How would that be achieved?

Comment: See, for example, [Chrome extension: Block page items before access](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41281291/)

Comment: Seems like a viable solution. I wonder if this is how the afore mentioned libraries do it?