# Can a browser make an HTTP request to itself?

Tags: javascript, http, browser

It's easy enough to use AJAX from a browser to an external address, (i.e. external to the browser, even if it's `localhost`) but I have a different question.

Is there some kind of object or service that would allow a browser to make (or mock) an HTTP request to itself, e.g. from JavaScript?

E.g. from Firefox I can see the following raw request:

```
GET /headers.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

And by using a PHP script (the aforementioned `headers.php` in the `GET` request):

```
<pre>
<?php
print_r(apache_request_headers ());
```

I can see the following on the page:

```
[Content-Type] => 
[Content-Length] => 0
[Upgrade-Insecure-Requests] => 1
[User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0
[Host] => localhost
[Accept-Language] => en-GB,en;q=0.5
[Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate
[Accept] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
[Connection] => keep-alive
[Cache-Control] => max-age=0
```

Can I get the same information via JavaScript, without making a call to a server script?

Comment: What do you mean by *"to itself"* What is the use-case you've got in mind ? Like that I can't really see what the browser does serve that you could request for... UserAgent stylesheets maybe ?

Comment: @Kaiido Use case: make a fake request, get the `Accept-Languages` request header which is otherwise unavailable without a server to echo the value back to the browser.

Comment: @CJDennis Are you trying to make a `HEAD` or `OPTIONS` request [Why does Fetch API Send the first PUT request as OPTIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42311018/), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42311018/why-does-fetch-api-send-the-first-put-request-as-options/42311206#comment71821815_42311018?

Comment: Not gathering what you are trying to achieve? What is requirement?

Comment: Isn't this `Accept-Languages` header the same as `navigator.languages` ?

Comment: @Kaiido No, that's the point.

Comment: Ok so now can you tell us how you get this header when it comes from a real server ? Does a dummy request to `about:blank` or even `data:text/plain,` works ? Also, your  question would benefit from an [edit] stating exactly what you are trying to achieve and why (e.g "I want to get the Accept Languages request header without the use of a server") instead of the current non-sense.

Comment: You can the request including `Accept-Language` header as a `.har` file at browser. Though the original Question does not ask how to get `Accept-Language` header, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It is currently unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @guest271314 How do you access the `.har` file from JavaScript?

Comment: You can create an extension or use `Network` tab at `DevTools`. Though that is beyond the scope of the actual Question.

Comment: So according to your edit, you have no way to get this info from javascript even when the request is made to a real sever (it's either dev-tools or server-side).

Comment: @Kaiido I know of no way. I'm not saying there is no way, just that if there is, I don't know it. If you know of a way would you be so kind as to tell me? I'm not talking about parsing the response from the server.

Comment: No and that's my point : you are trying to make something that you already can't do, in a different way. Your question should really be *"Is there a way to get the request headers from javascript"* And this question has probably already been asked before, but I'm afraid the answer will be "no" because XHR doesn't expose it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220149/how-do-i-access-the-http-request-header-fields-via-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can request either a `Blob URL` or a `data URI` see [Does Stack Overflow have an "echo page" to test AJAX requests, inside a code snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288902/does-stack-overflow-have-an-echo-page-to-test-ajax-requests-inside-a-code-sni/290948#290948), or use `ServiceWorker` to serve a specific `Response` [Chrome extension: Block page items before access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41281291/chrome-extension-block-page-items-before-access/). An empty string passed to either `XMLHttpRequest.open()` or `fetch()` requests the current URL.