# Processing fetch response - JS

Tags: javascript, web, fetch, response

I have the response after GET-request with `fetch`. I know that this response will return an Array. When I process it with `.json()` - everything is fine. But when I try to process same response with `.formData()`- it fails.
Here's the code:

```
fetch(fullPath)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((allData) => {
      console.log(allData);
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

same one with `response.formData()` doesn't work. 
So the question is - why we are not able to process the promise in first "then" with `.formData()` if the [off. doc says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Body) that `formData()` is also acceptable method for extracting a body from the response ?

Comment: Interesting.  Indeed the docs say `.formData` can be used in both request and response but the only examples in the docs are for requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `formData()` method will return an error if the response is not having the multipart/form-data type. It should have `key=value` entries. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47067312/multipart-http-response) where someone asks about designing a response with that format.

Something similar happens if you call the `json()` method on a response that is not valid JSON: that also triggers an exception.

Since `multipart/form-data` is rarely used as response content type, the `formData()` method is not often used either. The [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/formData) mentions it has some use for service workers:

> **Note**: This [method] is mainly relevant to service workers. If a user submits a form and a service worker intercepts the request, you could for example call `formData()` on it to obtain a key-value map, modify some fields, then send the form onwards to the server (or use it locally).

Comment: Thank's a lot for U'r answer !. I assumed that there is some kind of types mismatch but now I know it clearly.
But I also want to clarify one moment: why can't we consider an Array obj that comes in a response as the range of `key=value` entries ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but form-data type is a specific format. If the response data is not according to that format, but is (for instance) formatted as JSON, XML, or CSV, then the `formData()` method will not work, even when the data is really representing some array. It is the format in which that array is returned that determines with which method you can read it.

Comment: I'm sorry for the definitions that are, perhaps, wrong or not clearly enough - it's just a lack of practical experience. 
Thank U very much for Ur explanations.