# Update browser cache with javascript

Tags: javascript, browser-cache, browser-history

My web app renders asynchronously via javascript. The issue is that the browser caches a version of the page and then doesn't update the cache when I manipulate the DOM. Then when I click the back or forward buttons, the browser loads the cached version of the webpage, which is not the final version.

My patch is to force a page reload whenever a popstate event fires.

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', () => window.location.reload())
```

But that solution slows down the page load significantly.

I am wondering if there is a way to force a browser cache update whenever I manipulate the DOM. Something like:

```
window.location.forceCacheUpdate()
```

I want to be able to update the cache without reloading the entire page.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413234/how-to-prevent-caching-of-my-javascript-file
Or 
http://thisinterestsme.com/stop-javascript-cached/

in both cases you have to add additional text to your script

Comment: The browser caches HTML, not the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the updated HTML within `sessionStorage` then replace the static HTML request body with the locally stored HTML at `load` event of `window` or when navigation occurs, for example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="div"></div>
  <script>
    onload = () => {
      console.log(sessionStorage);
      const div = document.getElementById("div");
      if (sessionStorage.getItem('html') === null) {
        div.innerHTML = '<p>1</p>';
        sessionStorage.setItem('html', encodeURIComponent(div.innerHTML));
        setTimeout(() => { console.log('navigate'); history.back() }, 2000)
      } else {
        div.innerHTML = decodeURIComponent(sessionStorage.getItem('html'));
      }
      // do stuff
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

You can also utilize the [History interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) or `ServiceWorker` `ServiceWorker` [Chrome extension: Block page items before access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41281291/chrome-extension-block-page-items-before-access).

See [Persist variables between page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29986657/) for a range of solutions for storing data between `window` loads.

Comment: Unfortunately, the onload handler doesn't fire for the back/forward buttons. Do you know of an event that does fire when history is loaded?

Comment: @JeremyGottfried Is the `onload` attribute event handler attached to `<body>` dispatched?